# PHP mail() returns false logs are empty

Tags: debian, php

I have installed apache with PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 and I can't get mail to work, this is the code i'm using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo 'I am : ' . `whoami`;
$result = mail('*****','Testing 1 2 3','This is a test.');
echo '<hr>Result was: ' . ( $result === FALSE ? 'FALSE' : 'TRUE') . $result;
echo '<hr>';
echo phpinfo();
```

this is response I get:

```
I am : www-data
Result was: FALSE
```

In my php.ini i have edited two lines, this is how hey look right now:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f something@****.lt
sendmail_from = something@****.lt
```

`/var/log/mail.log` is completely empty even thou I have been trying various things for over an hour now.

I'm fairly new to linux so i'm pretty sure that I'm missing something obvious just can't seem to find in...

**EDIT** Forgot to mention that i do restart apache every time i make some changes to my configuration, and I'm using Debian 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install postfix or sendmail (Postfix would be preferred)

The php mail() function needs an MTA in any way.

Or you can use the complicated way and script an smtp Mailclass: email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/…

Or you can use phpmailer: phpmailer.worxware.com.

But to be able to use mail() you need an mta (Aka postfix or sendmail)

Comment: Is there really no way to make this work without installing extra things?

Comment: No. The php mail() function needs an MTA in any way.
Or you can use the complicatet way and script an smtp Mailclass: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm or you can use phpmailer: http://phpmailer.worxware.com.
But to be able to use mail() you need an mta (Aka postfix or sendmail)

Comment: I've given +1, but it's more for the additional info in the comment than the original answer.

Comment: I'm also very very surprised if a stock copy of Debian doesn't already have an MTA installed by default.

Comment: SDC: You are right. I edited the answer to be more informative.

Answer (score 2):

the mail() Function is configured on many Ways on many Servers.  Using a mail Class with SMTP Support will save you much time. I prefer:

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

On the other side, sending Mails per SMTP Server works better with Spam Filters etc.

Comment: Yeah i was able to install sSMTP and now i get this error in my log
Cannot open mail.**.lt:25

Comment: and mail.***.lt is usualy responding? e.g. per telnet/netcat?